# difference between the work of scopes, namespaces and frames in import and from import in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

*tldr: how namespaces, frames, scopes are different in "import" and "from import" in Python?*

I'm trying to understand the intricacies of scopes in import and from import in Python but I can't understand.

So let's imagine what we have 2 .py files:

```
helper.py:
x = 10
```

```
main.py:
#there's nothing yet
```

So when we use import operator in `main.py`:

```
main.py:
import helper
```

So here import is a way of linking a name, and it binds a name to one specific scope. An import statement in Python is similar to defining a variable.
In other words, when we import module, a module object is created in memory, then it is linked with a name and saved to the namespace dictionary, and we can then access the attributes of that object via dot notation.
The import statement creates a new frame for executing a module in the same way that calling functions creates frames for executing those functions.

*My first question* is if we change the attribute in the main file where the module was imported, (when the script will run) like:

```
main.py:
import helper

helper.x = 42
```

will this x change in `helper.py`?

*Second question* - how are scopes, frames and namespaces are working in "from import" construction?
So I undestand that in namespace dictionary an "x" key is created with a value of x, but how is it done?
I suggest it's not copy like youtube says, and here *my 3rd question and 4th question*:

*if after "from import" we change the x variable in main.py - will it change in helper.py?*

I also know that the module is loaded only once and can be reloaded:

from imp import reload
reload(<Module object>)

*but why won't identifiers, imported using the "from import" statement, not be reloaded?*

so my questions are purely theoretical. If I wrote something wrong from what I know, please tell me.

I've tried to google + youtube but really can't find those little details.

Comment: You could define a function in `helper.py` to print `x`, and use it to check what's happening.

Comment: "will this x change in helper.py?" did you check and see? "if after "from import" we change the x variable in main.py - will it change in helper.py?" did you check and see?

Comment: "So here import is a way of linking a name, and it binds a name to one specific scope." You are conflating two things here. The name is simply bound to a `module` object, which *has* a global scope for use by functions defined in the module.

Comment: `from module import x` is equivalent to `import module; x = module.x; del module` So you create a *new variable* that refers to the same object (at the time of import). The semantics are the same as assigning any variable

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, `helper.py` doesn't have a variable. It's a source file, and it has an assignment statement that will define a variable when it gets executed. This distinction matters because we can write a script that imports itself, resulting in two modules (`__main__` and `helper`) defined by the same file (`helper.py`):

```
import helper

x = 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    helper.x = 5
    print(x)
    print(helper.x)
```

`python3 helper.py` will output

```
3
5
```

`from foo import x` does two things: it defines (if necessary) the module `foo`, then define a *new* variable in the current scope and *initializes* it using the value of the global variable in `foo`. That is, `x` and `foo.x` remain two separate variables:

```
>>> import sys; from sys import argv
>>> argv = 9
>>> sys.argv
['']
```

Comment: So, now I understand the mechanism from import but I have a dumb question about import:
Do I understand correctly that import in your example works the same way as from import? And the mechanism itself is identical, and namspaces, scopes does not play a role here?

Comment: Yes, as pointed out in the comments, `from foo import x` first imports `foo`, then binds `x` to `foo.x` in the current scope, but *without* binding the name `foo` to the imported module.

Comment: Thank you @chepner, now it's all clean to me + I've understand now why reload() doen't work with from mport